# How to upload image into database using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload an image into the database. The image is not uploading properly, how can I fix it?

The image path is uploading into database like this: `{"image":"phpV3IZnF.png"}`

it should be like this: `phpV3IZnF.png`

**Controller**

```
               public function servicesaction(Request $request)
               {
                  $this->validate($request,[
                  'name' => 'required',
                  'description'=>'required',
                  'image' =>'required']); 
                  $name=$request->get('name');
                  $description = $request->get('description');      
                  $image = $request->file('image');      
                  $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                  Storage::disk('cms')->put($image->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  
                  File::get($image));
                  $content = new Services;
                  $content->image = $image->getFilename().'.'.$extension;;
                  check = Services::where('id', $content->id)->select('image')- 
                  >create(['service_name'=>$name,'description'=> 
                  $description,'image'=>$content ])->get();
                  return back()->with('success', 'Success Successfully Inserted')- 
                  >with('path',  $check);
                    }
```

Comment: Change `'image'=>$content` to `'image'=>$content->image` in your `create` function

Comment: you can upload image in your host and save file_path into your DB.

Answer (score 0):

you can get file name like below

```
$fileName = md5($image->getClientOriginalName() . time()) . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

then save the name into database

Replace servicesaction function with below code

```html
 public function servicesaction(Request $request)
               {
                  $this->validate($request,[
                  'name' => 'required',
                  'description'=>'required',
                  'image' =>'required']); 
                  $name=$request->get('name');
                  $description = $request->get('description');      
                  $image = $request->file('image');      
                  $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                  Storage::disk('cms')->put($image->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  
                  File::get($image));
                  $content = new Services;
                  $content->image =$image->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$extension;;
                  check = Services::where('id', $content->id)->select('image')- 
                  >create(['service_name'=>$name,'description'=> 
                  $description,'image'=>$content ])->get();
                  return back()->with('success', 'Success Successfully Inserted')- 
                  >with('path',  $check);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change getFilename() to getClientOriginalName() 
Like this

```
$extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension()
$content->image = $image->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Change `'image'=>$content` to `'image'=>$content->image` in the your `create` function

```
check = Services::where('id', $content->id)->select('image')
   ->create(['service_name'=>$name,'description'=> $description, 'image'=>$content->image ]) //use $content->image here
   ->get();
```